# Comunicacion serial COM con python

Tags: python, pyserial, com

quisiera comunicarme con puerto serial en python, pero obtengo error, creo que la trama no esta bien definida (tengo conocimientos basicos en python) mando la informacion para el serial

[![serie][1]][1][![serie][2]][2][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5K2s.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDTtP.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDY0g.png

codigo con ayuda de gpt

```
import serial
import time

header = b'\xEF\x01'
module_address = b'\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF'
package_identifier = b'\x01'
instruction_code = b'\x03'
paraMetro=b'\0F'
password= b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 57600,serial.EIGHTBITS,serial.PARITY_NONE,serial.STOPBITS_ONE,5)
print(ser)
checksum = bytes([(sum(header + module_address + package_identifier + instruction_code + paraMetro + password) >> 8) & 0xFF, (sum(header + module_address + package_identifier + instruction_code + password)) & 0xFF])
command = header + module_address + package_identifier + instruction_code + password + checksum
print(checksum)
ser.write(command)
print(command)
response = ser.read(10)  # Leer 10 bytes de la respuesta, ajusta el valor según la longitud de la respuesta esperada
print(response)

if response[0] == 0x00:
    print("Contraseña correcta")
elif response[0] == 0x01:
    print("Error al recibir el paquete")
elif response[0] == 0x13:
    print("Contraseña incorrecta")
else:
    print("Respuesta desconocida")


ser.close()
```

otro codigo con ayuda de chatgpt

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 57600,serial.EIGHTBITS,serial.PARITY_NONE,serial.STOPBITS_ONE,5)

header = 0xEF01
module_address = 0xFFFFFFFF 
package_identifier = 0x01
instruction_code = 0x07
password = 0x00000000 

checksum = (header + module_address + package_identifier + instruction_code + password) & 0xFFFF
command_packet = bytearray()
command_packet.extend(header.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
command_packet.extend(module_address.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
command_packet.append(package_identifier)
command_packet.append(instruction_code)
command_packet.extend(password.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
command_packet.extend(checksum.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))

# Enviar el paquete de comando al módulo
ser.write(command_packet)
print(command_packet)
# Leer la respuesta del módulo
response = ser.read(12) 
print(response)
# Verificar el código de confirmación en la respuesta
if len(response) == 12:
    if response[0] == 0xEF and response[1] == 0x01 and response[3] == 0x07 and response[4] == 0x03:
        confirmation_code = response[5]
        if confirmation_code == 0x00:
            print("Contraseña correcta")
        elif confirmation_code == 0x01:
            print("Error al recibir el paquete")
        elif confirmation_code == 0x13:
            print("Contraseña incorrecta")
    else:
        print("Respuesta inválida del módulo")
else:
    print("Respuesta incompleta del módulo")
ser.close()
```

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO :)

Adjunte algunas imágenes datasheet sobre la trama correcta, creo que no aplicó bien Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Y el error es...?

Comment: Procura además no usar ChatGPT si no entiendes lo que estás haciendo. Es útil si ya tienes noción previa, pero no para hacer algo completamente _desde cero_.

Comment: El error retorna -1

Comment: Pregunto a chatgpt para tener una idea de cómo usar serial

Comment: Adjunte imágenes de como debería ser la trama, creo que no estoy elaborando bien la trama, gracias

Comment: No hay imágenes, te aconsejo revisar el formato de tu pregunta para que se muestren las imágenes y cambiar el código de ChatGPT por código propio.